# How to install Ubuntu on Acer V5-122p computer

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, windows-8, acer

I have problems installing Ubuntu on my Acer V5-122p. Where can I find tutorials how to do this?

Comment: Just disable secure boot and fast boot + enable Legacy support in UEFI. Should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using my V5-122 in over a year now, no problem.

from 13.4 via 13.10 now running 14.4

you have tu use the graphics-drivers from amd.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the possibility to use [Ubuntu certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) only.
Alternatively, there is hardware that is certified to work with other Linux distributions.